# Lucene cartesian product diferent documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, lucene

I have 3 indexed documents:

1. Cars: Toyota (`gt, gtX, gtx12`), Ford (corola...), Volkswagen (`gtS`), Tesla...
2. Car models: `gt, gtX, gtx12`
3. Car colors: `white, red`

Example search query: "`gt*`"

---

Should return:

> 1. Volkswagen gtS white
> 2. Volkswagen gtS red
> 3. Toyota gt white
> 4. Toyota gt red
> 5. Toyota gtx12 white
> 6. Toyota gtx12 red
> 7. Toyota gtX red
> 8. Toyota gtX white

I can't add them to index like '`Toyota gt`', '`Toyota gtx`'... because there will be a relay huge index (even more then 50gb in my case, and search is slow).

---

I implemented in my own: Search by "`car`" then by "`models`" then merge but I'm interested if lucene can handle it.

Comment: What is your actual use case for this?

Comment: Let's say we have phrase "Get number of people in $country for $gender", where $country is variable (USA, Poland, United....) and $gender is a variable too.

When user type "Get number of people in*" should get the result of all combination (cartesian product):

1. Get number of people in USA women,
2. Get number of people in USA men,
3. Get number of people in Poland women
.....
and so on

Comment: Wouldn't that be a sum across a facet in that case, given that you have documents with ("USA", "<statename>", "Men", 32) or something similar?

Comment: I don't have document  with "USA", "<statename>", "Men", 32. I have different documents one with "USA", other with "statename", other with "Men"....

Comment: No, my point is that Lucene-based technologis as a document based search engine, and that your data has to be somewhere. Where is you data? Where does the number of people come from? What do you want to sum? What is the data structure you're trying to work with? Those numbers has to be structured somewhere, and you have to have some processing of the text if you're trying to do natural language queries.

Comment: Number of people let's say is calculated by other service, i just need to create search combinations. I don't have to sum, that is doing that service.

Comment: How do you define valid combinations today? (50GB isn't a very large index, but the number of documents is usually more important)

Comment: Let's say i have 200 of countries ($country variables) and 50 states 200*50 = 10.000, but i have one other variable that contains more then 1 milion so i will have a lot of documents (1.000.000 * 50 * 200)...